# What is the curl of $k\hat{r}/r^n$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, differentiation, vector-fields, calculus

I'm trying to find the curl of ${\bf F}(r) = k \hat{r}/r^n$. I think that this converts to:

$$
k\left(\frac{\hat{x}}{r} + \frac{\hat{y}}{r} + \frac{\hat{z}}{r}\right)\frac{1}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{n/2}}
$$

I think that the determinant should look like:

$$
\hat{x}\left(\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial F_y}{ \partial z}\right) + \hat{y} \left(\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial x}\right) + \hat{z}\left(\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y}\right)
$$

I know that either each of the contents of the brackets equals zero or each individual derivative equals zero.

If I assume that it should be $\hat{x}/r$, the first derivative equals:

$$
\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial y} = k\left(-(n+2)y(x^2+ y^2 + z^2)^{-(n+4)/2}\right)
$$

Thanks, I appreciate all the help you can give me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively speaking, the field ${\bf F}(r)$ is radial, so its curl is zero,

$$
\nabla \times {\bf F} = 0
$$

Below I show a proof, which is based on two facts

1. $$
   \nabla \times (\phi{\bf A}) = \phi (\nabla \times {\bf A}) + (\nabla \phi)\times {\bf A} \tag{1}
   $$
2. $$
   \nabla \times {\bf r} = {\bf 0} \tag{2}
   $$

this can be shown to be true by using

$$
\nabla\times {\bf r} = \epsilon_{ijk}\partial_i x_j\hat{e}_k = \epsilon_{ijk}\delta_{ij}\hat{e}_k = \epsilon_{iik}\hat{e}_k = {\bf 0}
$$

Taking this into account

\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla \times \left(k\frac{\hat{r}}{r^n} \right) &=& 
\nabla \times \left(k\frac{{\bf r}}{r^{n + 1}} \right) \\
&\stackrel{(1)}{=}& \frac{k}{r^{n+1}}(\nabla\times {\bf r}) + k\left(\nabla\frac{1}{r^{n+1}} \right)\times {\bf r} \\
&\stackrel{(2)}{=}& -k(n+1)\frac{{\bf r}}{r^{n+2}}\times {\bf r} = 0
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Although perfectly correct I still would not call *this* derivation intuitive. Instead one may wish to argue that because of the radial nature of the vector field the concentric spheres centered at the singularity (here the origin) must be orthogonal to the field everywhere, hence they are the equipotential surfaces whose gradients are the field, in other words the field is conservative.

Comment: @hyportnex What I meant by intuitive was just the first line, what follows is a formal explanation